# while performing search operation in node.js, it returns all properties of a search object. How should one avoid it from returning all properties?

Tags: node.js, querying

```
const lodash = require('lodash');
const {User, validate} = require('../models/user');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const express = require('express');
// const auth = require('./auth');
 const router = express.Router();

router.get('/:name', (req, res) => {
const regex = new RegExp(req.params.name, 'i');
User.find({name:regex}).then((result) => {
//res.send(lodash.pick(result, ['_id', 'name', 'number']));
res.json(result);
})
});
```

> It returns all properties of a search object including sensitive information too. How should one avoid that ?

Answer (score 0):

Default JS operator `delete` could be a good helper for you.
It can be used to specify the fields you need to remove before sending the result.
Here is an example of deleting `_id` field from `result` object:

```
let result = {name:'James',number:'12334',_id:3};
delete result._id;
// now object will looks like this 
// {name:'James',number:'12334'}
res.json(result);
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved by adding more information on what the code does and how it helps the OP.

Comment: @Tyler2P thnx for the mention. Added some description